# JSON request using objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I know there are hundreds of questions on here about JSON, and how to use it. I am not looking for that; I am looking for HOW do I determine if a website actually USES JSON so that I can get the information from the website into my application.

For example, I know that flikr, google, and more uses JSON, but how do I know if hunting websites or sports websites use it?

Any help or advice would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Ask the website owner

Comment: ha okay, that does seem like the right idea. Is there nothing at the end, like .json or anything in the actual url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for link to the API documentation in the footer of the website.
If there is none, probably they don't offer any kind of public API.

You can also try to contact the website owner and ask him.

Comment: That is very valuable information, thank you.